# Elementor URL control is not working - Returning an array

Tags: php, elementor

I'm building a custom widget for Elementor. I added a URL field in that widget but for some unknown reason, it is not working.

After clicking on the link, it is redirecting the user to this http://example.com/array

Here is my code

Elementor URL Control

```
           $this->add_control(
            'service_button_url', [
                'label'          => esc_html__( 'Service Button URL', 'dentist' ),
                'type'           => Controls_Manager::URL,
                'default' => [
                    'url' => ''
                ]
            ]
        );
        
       
<a href="<?php echo $settings['service_button_url']['url']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary service-btn">Test</a>
```

The href tag would echo the following URL http://example.com/array

What am I doing wrong? All other controls are working fine like media and textbox

Comment: See this official documentation https://developers.elementor.com/docs/controls/classes/control-url/

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
                  $this->add_control(
            'service_button_url', [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Service Button URL', 'dentist' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::URL,
                'default' => [
                    'url' => ''
                ]
                'label_block' => true,
            ]
        );
    protected function render() { 
        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
                if ( ! empty( $settings['service_button_url']['url'] ) ) {
            $this->add_link_attributes( 'service_button_url', $settings['service_button_url'] );
        }
?>
    <a class="btn btn-primary service-btn" <?php echo $this->get_render_attribute_string( 'service_button_url' ); ?>>Test</a>

<?php
}
```